# Amasty Extension Install Compile Error

Tags: error, navigation, amasty, compile

Argento Stripes Theme (same error on blank luma) - Magento 2.4.3

please can somone help I am trying to install manually at the moment trying to get amasty Improved Layered Navigation Pro module-shopby-pro - in admin when I am clicking on the Stores Configuration Improved Layered Navigation getting this error

```
<style>.highlighted { background-color: #DFF7FF!important; }</style>
<form action="https://example.com/admin/admin/syst...1ac8816bb4f545d4f8da4eaf8de/section/amshopby/" method="post" id="config-edit-form"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="sHM7UVKujT164Ndi" /></div>
<div class="accordion">
An error has happened during application run. See excep
```

I spend 4 hours on this and cant fix this -

```
[2022-08-24 12:21:04] main.CRITICAL: Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\UrlBuilder $urlBuilder ] of Amasty\ShopbySeo\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontController class {"report_id":"7005216ea0715a1a00f74a5a249adc94abbc6d85b58fea9b71950f0363edbb2e","exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: 0): Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Amasty\\ShopbyBase\\Model\\UrlBuilder $urlBuilder ] of Amasty\\ShopbySeo\\Plugin\\Framework\\App\\FrontController class at /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:51, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Amasty\\ShopbyBase\\Model\\UrlBuilder does not exist at /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:71)"} []
[2022-08-24 12:24:57] main.CRITICAL: Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\UrlBuilder $urlBuilder ] of Amasty\ShopbySeo\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontController class {"report_id":"7005216ea0715a1a00f74a5a249adc94abbc6d85b58fea9b71950f0363edbb2e","exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: 0): Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Amasty\\ShopbyBase\\Model\\UrlBuilder $urlBuilder ] of Amasty\\ShopbySeo\\Plugin\\Framework\\App\\FrontController class at /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:51, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Amasty\\ShopbyBase\\Model\\UrlBuilder does not exist at /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:71)"} []
[2022-08-24 14:27:22] main.CRITICAL: Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\FilterSetting\IsMultiselect $isMultiselect ] of Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontController class {"report_id":"48753749d40910de20c7e88d022420d127a0075ea530e3173d710fd74c731dc0","exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: 0): Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> Amasty\\ShopbyBase\\Model\\FilterSetting\\IsMultiselect $isMultiselect ] of Amasty\\Shopby\\Plugin\\Framework\\App\\FrontController class at /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:51, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Amasty\\ShopbyBase\\Model\\FilterSetting\\IsMultiselect does not exist at /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:71)"} []
[2022-08-24 14:30:32] main.CRITICAL: Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\FilterSetting\IsMultiselect $isMultiselect ] of Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontController class {"report_id":"48753749d40910de20c7e88d022420d127a0075ea530e3173d710fd74c731dc0","exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: 0): Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> Amasty\\ShopbyBase\\Model\\FilterSetting\\IsMultiselect $isMultiselect ] of Amasty\\Shopby\\Plugin\\Framework\\App\\FrontController class at /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:51, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Amasty\\ShopbyBase\\Model\\FilterSetting\\IsMultiselect does not exist at /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:71)"} []
```

I did run

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy –f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Compile error is showing like this aswell

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
1/9 [===>------------------------] 11% < 1 sec 149.0 MiBInterface 'Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\FilterDataLoader\AdapterInterface' not found#0 /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#1 /home/example.com/xjuedtyxypg/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
2. when trying to install ShopbyBrand it gives this error in SSH
URL key for specified store already exists

I understand this may be another issue relating to url duplicate - but how would i check for this and fix it?  -   Thank You
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````